# Crystal reports Record number not including "suppressed records(detail section)"

Tags: record, suppress

How can get the record number in details section not including the suppressed?

I have tried the following:
1. Right Click on any of the fields and select "Format Field.."
2. In the "Format" editor, go to "Common" tab. 
4. Now go to the formula button "X+2" beside "Display String" and place the following code:

```html
numberVar x; 
WhilePrintingRecords ; 
x:=x+1; 
ToText({Employee.Employee ID},0) \\<Database Record>
```

5. Created formula @aa and placed the following code:

```html
numberVar x; 
WhilePrintingRecords ; 
x
```

but it gives me a record number starting from 0. I want it to start from 1. can anybody help me?

Comment: just edited formula from @aa numberVar x; WhilePrintingRecords;x+1

Answer (score 0):

I Used of this way and formula in my section :

> Format Section  -> [My Section] -> Suppress(No Drill Down)

```
{mydataSet_TTX.IsValid}= 0
```

And Use A Running total with count filed  For Row Number Then For Prevention Record That not show in report "that Suppressed" Use This formula for Running Total

> Your Running Total -> Right Click -> Edit Running Total - > Evaluate 
>   -> Use a formula

```
NOT({mydataSet_TTX.IsValid}= 0)
```

After change this parts , save report design and get preview … row number is corrected ... Record number not including “suppressed records(detail section)”

good luck.